# Is it possible to use stack of custom picture as the bars in a bar chart?

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, plotly, bar-chart

[coin stack bar chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5bk0.png)

I have data that I'd like to plot, and instead of regular vertical bars showing the value of the y-axis, I'd like to either:

fill up the bar with a picture (for example coin images, stacked one upon one)
is this possible? can anyone tell me how to achieve this, need this graph for my frontend application , can anyone suggest any JavaScript library I am using JavaScript at frontend.

can I use custom coin images and make stack instead of a plain bar graph. My client wants the graph exactly the image I have attached and I have explored so many options but not able to find any suitable solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! Which library are you using? Did you already try to solve the problem and have a script on which the community can comment?

Comment: @FarrukhNormuradov I am currently using plotly.js but I am open for new suggestions. Yes I have tried to solve this with chart.js library. code -- var img = new Image();
img.src = 'coin6.png';  var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d')
var fillPattern = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');      I am using createPattern() to fill the background inside bars of bar graph. but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Please, add this to your question.